# prove that the fucntion 2 + (x /4) > square root (4 + x) for a

Tags: analysis

my steps:

let h(x)=2+x/4-sqrt(x+4)
d/dx h(x)>0 since 1/4-1/(2sqrt(X+4))>0 FOR ALL X>0 so h is continuous and diffeentiable .h is striclty inccreasing fo x>0

is this right?

Comment: Is it $\dfrac{2+x}{4}$ or $2+\dfrac{x}{4}$ ?

Comment: OH SORRY ITS 2+(x/4) @PrasunBiswas

Comment: @AxelFoley Please let me know if my answer suffices.  I really want to give you the best answer I can give you.

Comment: @Dr.MV yees it is thank you!

Comment: Pleased to hear!

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{(4+x)}\le \sqrt{\left(4+x+\frac{x^2}{16}\right)}=\sqrt{\left(2+\frac{x}{4}\right)^2}=\left|2+\frac{x}{4}\right|=2+\frac{x}{4}$$

Since $x>-4$ by assumption.  Note that the inequality is strict for $x>0$.

---

Another way to show this is to let $f(x) = 2+\frac14 x-\sqrt{x+4}$.  Then, $f'(x) =\frac14-\frac12 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+4}}$.  For $x=0$, $f=0$.  And for $x>0$, $f'(x)>0$. Thus, $f>0$ for $x>0$.

Comment: this aint the inequality aksed by OP

Comment: $x=0$ leads to equality

Comment: @WillieRosario I addressed your comment with a second method.

Comment: @GabrielH  I addressed your comment with a note.

Comment: @Dr.MV Okay, I removed my comment.

Comment: @GabrielH Thank you.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

easy:

2 + x/4 > $\sqrt{4 + x} $ iff 4 + x + $\frac{x^2}{16}$ > 4 + x iff $\frac{x^2}{16} > 0$

But this true since

$$ \boxed{ x^2 \geq 0 } $$

is always true.